# Typescript - how to specify a type that allows arbitrary additional keys to be added to a base interface

Tags: typescript

How would I specify an interface in Typescript that allows arbitrary additional keys on top of a set of required keys? That is to say, the interface extends another interface arbitrarily. E.g.:

```
interface base {
  foo: string;
}

const arr:<<type extends base>>[] = [ // I don't know how to do this!
 {
   foo: 'fie', // acceptable
 },
 {
   foo: 'fum',
   bar: 'boo', // also acceptable
 },
 {
   bar: 'bee' // not acceptable
 },
];
```

Comment: So you just want your interface to inherit from another interface?

Comment: @mwilson don't want to specify *how* it extends the interface.

Comment: Ah. I see. What Christian just posted should work for you then. TS won't allow you to just add things arbitrarily. In order to do that, you wouldn't use an Interface, or you would use `any`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a record-like index signature to any interface as follows:

```js
interface Base {
    value: number;
}

interface Extension extends Base {
    [key: string]: unknown;
}
```

In addition to the properties from `Base` the new interface `Extension` will now accept any further arbitrary properties with keys of type `string`.

Another alternative, maybe more human-readable solution, is to write a type that extends your `Base` and the `Record` type:

```js
type TypeExtension = Base & Record<string, unknown>;
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Christians answer, you could also just do it one `interface`:

```
interface IMyBaseInterface {
    foo: string;
    [key: string]: any;
}


const arr: IMyBaseInterface[] = [
    { foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo' },
    { foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo', test: 1 }
]
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkCeAhOBnCVcaeJZAbwFgAoZO5GAe0YC5k8wpQBzAbhvrIA2gGsImNhy4huAXTZwQmftQC+NDdQSMQHZHChQ2GHPkLFYiCENnIAvMIH1yDZmwDkAIwPuANMm8jZHcmRndkVV8nOhdQj0C-AIMPUMTIDjYARgiaWSA)

Comment: You can drop the type assertions if I am not mistaken.

Comment: And I propose to use `unknown` over `any` for even further type-safety.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic what will unknown accept that any won't?

Comment: `unknown` won't allow you any unsafe access such as function invocation aree array index access while any basically disabled all type-checking of Typescript for that particular variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Union types. The extra keys may be of any type, and will have their own type checking. Here I used `{ extra: any; }` as an example, but you could use `any`thing else :) .

```
export type Foo = {
  nice: boolean;
  count: number;
} | {
  [key: string]: { extra: any; };
};
```

Let's test it:

Intellisense for the required keys:

[image: Intellisense screenshot 1]

Intellisense for the extra keys:

[image: Intellisense screenshot 2]

No type errors:

[image: Screenshot showing no type errors]